# Telegram Bot not working with Webhook, programme is running but not getting any response

Tags: python, heroku, python-telegram-bot

I have create a telegram bot in python but I am unable to set webhook. After some research I have set the webhook but it's not working. the code is working with start_polling() method but stop working in heroku server after some time so I want to run the code using webhook.
The code is running properly but not getting any response from telegram

```
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))        
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=PORT, url_path=token,
                          webhook_url='https://git.heroku.com/pytelestock.git' + token)
```

When run the api got this error.

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://git.heroku.com/pytelestock.git1851418449:token","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":2,"last_error_date":1622897956,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}}
```

As i am new in this field i don't know why i am getting the error and how to solve this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook_url should rather be `'pytelestock.herouk.com/' + token`.